# Get Response from failed HTTP-Request in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, error-handling, httprequest, observer-pattern

In oder to present the User the Error of his instert into my Backend i want to show the Error-Message which is part of the awnser of the Request.

[image: An example Response]

Here is the Code i tried, but it doesnt work.

[image]

[image]

As you can see the anwser is always undiefiend.

Comment: Actually we can't see this. What line is 134? 500 means there's an issue with your server.